# Magento 1.7 - get category url returns null

Tags: image, magento, categories

I have an issue driving me crazy ...
I load a category by id, and want do display the category image:

```
$subCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subcat);
echo $subCategory->getImageUrl();
```

But the imageurl is null. In database in catalog_category_entity_varchar there is definitly an image saved for this category id. var_dump($subCategory) contains **["image"]=> NULL** and  **["thumbnail"]=> NULL** although these two values are stored in database.

I already updated indexes, and deleted catalog image cache. I spent hours on google and tried many other methods, but now i'm running out of ideas and hope s.o. can help me.

Comment: $_category->getImageUrl() is defiantly the function to be calling on the category. Your var_dump is returning null for both image and thumbnail. Are you sure that the id being passed in is the correct id for the category you want? Are you sure you that there is actually an image assigned to category (check via admin interface). The frontend code, actually loads the category by store so you could try doing $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())->load($categoryId)->getImageUrl()

Comment: As a follow up to Ashley's comment -- check this to make sure the actual category is loading: Zend_Debug::dump($subCategory->getData())

Comment: I tried again today, and i was able to get the image data with `$category->getData('image')`. I have no idea why this didn't work yet.